# Python using class with loops working with time and datetime doesn't reset the timers

Tags: python

I have tried to work with a while loop to keep my script running, I use time to track the time it takes to run. Simpler code it's something like this:

```
import time
import datetime

class Test:
    start = time.time()
    dateStart = datetime.datetime.now()

    def end(self):
        time.sleep(10)
        print(time.time() - self.start)
        print(datetime.datetime.now() - self.dateStart)

while True:
    test = Test()
    test.end()
```

and also tried with:

```
import time
import datetime

class Test:
    start = time.time()
    dateStart = datetime.datetime.now()

    def end(self):
        time.sleep(10)
        print(time.time() - self.start)
        print(datetime.datetime.now() - self.dateStart)

def runClass(classtest):
    test = classtest()
    test.end()

while True:
    runClass(Test)
```

But the timers are not set to 0 after each reset, they accumulate. The rest of the values I have in my big class do reset to the initial value they have after the class is created, but not dates. Is there something I'm missing about how python manage time and classes? I'm starting to use classes more, so maybe I'm missing something about how they are define in memory?

Comment: can you explain the line `test = classtest()` ?

Comment: @balderman fixed it, I had returned the code to the 2nd state to the first and forgot to fix that.

Comment: Please update the code in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing is how classes are defined and instances created.

Your code:

```py
class Test:
    start = time.time()
    dateStart = datetime.datetime.now()
```

executes exactly once when `class Test` is defined.

What you meant to write was this:

```py
class Test:
    def __init__(self)
        self.start = time.time()
        self.dateStart = datetime.datetime.now()
    ...
```

The `__init__()` method is executed every time `test = Test()` executes which is what you are after.

btw, I think that your line: `test = classtest()` should be `test = Test()`

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Does it work the same for variables with int or str? Because I have a lot of counters set to 0 the same way, but they do reset.

Comment: You can initialise *any* variables in either way. You should do what is appropriate. Variables that can be set once, but which instances need to read can be set the first way. Variables which each instance needs set differently, or need to be written to independently need to be set within the `__init__()` method.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. You meant the way the instances of time and datetime were created. I get it now, thank you very much.